# Closed Tensorflow FIFO queue not throwing exception

Tags: exception, queue, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the following code on a CPU machine:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


feature_dim = 3
nr_frames = 8

# create dummy features and targets
features = np.zeros((nr_frames, feature_dim))
targets = np.zeros((nr_frames))
for frame in range(nr_frames):
    for item in range(feature_dim):
        features[frame, item] = int("%d%d" % (frame, item))
    targets[frame] = int("%d" % (frame))


feature_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, feature_dim])
target_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])

fifo = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=10000,
                    dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32],
                    shapes=[[feature_dim], []],
                    names=['features', 'targets'] )
enqueue_op = fifo.enqueue_many({'features' : feature_input,
                                'targets' :  target_input})

data = fifo.dequeue()

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord=coord)

# push dummy data to queue
sess.run(enqueue_op,
         feed_dict = {feature_input: features,
                      target_input : targets})
fifo.close()


for i in range(12):
    print "\niteration %d" % i
    print "elements in databuffer: %d" % sess.run(fifo.size())
    x = sess.run(data)
    print x
```

I'm basically creating some dummy features and targets (for a classification task), push the data to a TF FIFO queue and close the queue to simulate some behavior I will need in the fully-fledged system code.

Since the FIFO queue is closed, I'd expect the dequeue() function to throw an tf.errors.OutOfRangeError exception, once the queue gets empty, as explained in
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#queues

This should happen after iteration 7, since we have 8 elements in the features/target data. However, the program just keeps hanging - I guess due to some blocking call.

What am I doing wrong here?

RCB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fifo.close()` call in your code doesn't actually close the queue: instead it returns a `tf.Operation` that, when run, will close the queue. If you replace it with the following code, you should see the exception as expected:

```
close_op = fifo.close()
sess.run(close_op)

# Now `sess.run(data)` will return values until all of the elements in the queue
# have been dequeued.
```

Comment: Wow, thanks mrry!
That was extremely quick and it works. :)
Loving TF more every day.